# Adding Three new column in sencha grid before thr first column

Tags: extjs, gxt

Suppose i have a sencha grid which has  4 columns already existing. But when I try to add 3 additional columns, the other four columns already existing in the grid stop showing up properly. Is this the right way to add the columns and can we add multiple columns at the same time to a sencha grid. I am using extjs 4.2.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
     if(!gradeColumnExists){
            var categoryGradeColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
                text: 'Grade',
                dataIndex: 'categoryGrade',
                flex: 1
            });
            grid.headerCt.insert(0, categoryGradeColumn);
            categoryGradeColumn.hidden=false;
            grid.getView().refresh();
        }
        if(!weightColumnExists){
            var weightColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
                text: 'Weight',
                dataIndex: 'weight',
                flex: 1
            });
            grid.headerCt.insert(0, weightColumn);
            weightColumn.hidden=false;
            grid.getView().refresh();
        }
        if(!categoryColumnExists){
            var categoryColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
                text: 'Category',
                dataIndex: 'categoryName',
                flex: 4
            });
            grid.headerCt.insert(0, categoryColumn);
            categoryColumn.hidden=false;
            grid.getView().refresh();
       }
```

Comment: If it's just a few columns I would just include them all at the beginning and just show/hide the ones you want. Otherwise, I typically use the reconfigure method when I have a grid where the columns need to be changed dynamically: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure

Comment: yup that worked!..thank you so much!